# "this" in JavaScript objects vs. jQuery $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, this

I've stumbled over a problem. I have an object method `foo` defined as:

```
var obj = {
    foo: function() {
        $('.personName').mouseover(function() {
            this.highlight($(this).attr('faceIndex'));
        });
    }
}
```

So what should happen is that whenever the mouse cursor is over an HTML object of type `personName`, the `obj.highlight` method should be called with the `faceIndex` value from the HTML object as an argument. However I apparently have a clash between two this's: the one of jQuery and the one of JavaScript (referencing to `obj` from inside `obj`).

What can (should) I do? Have I violated some good programming practice?

Comment: `this` is one of the biggest pain points in JS. You'll have to assign the obj this to a local variable so that you can use that it in the inner function.

Comment: Don't get confused. When you wrap things in jQuery $() function `this` becomes a jQuery object. Just to shed some lights: http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/#When_this_is_most_misunderstood_and_becomes_tricky and http://stackoverflow.com/a/26644821/1672895

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript "this" keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword), especially [this answer referring to jQuery callbacks](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3127609/7469).

Comment: @Mathletics: You are right, bur careful search for quite some time didn't reveal that answer. I'd suggest you add this link as one more answer here, for better findability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: do

```
    $('.personName').mouseover(function(event) {
        obj.highlight($(event.target).attr('faceIndex'));
    });
```

Longer explanation:

Javascript doesn't *really* have a concept of `this`. At least not in the way you're used to thinking of it. Oh there's a keyword alright, and it kind of does the thing you expect a lot of the times but it doesn't work the way that you probably think.

The fact of the matter is that in javascipt, `this` is no different than any other parameter. Let me show you.

Most people are aware that in javascript you can invoke functions like this `doSomething(param1, param2)` or like this `doSomething.call(null, param1, param2)`. If you wanted, you can write all function invocations using `.call`

See that `null` there? Anything you pass in there is what `this` gets set to.

```
doSomething.call(null, param1, param2);
doSomething.call(obj, param1, param2);
doSomething.call(window, param1, param2);
doSomething.call("foobar", param1, param2);
```

If you don't use `.call` the runtime just takes a guess at what value you want there.

So given this, consider that the only difference between `this` and any other parameter is that you don't get to give `this` a name! Your problem is that you have two function scopes and the inner one has a variable named `this` which hides the outer one's `this`.

Solution: don't use `this`. Most libraries in fact (jquery included), don't force you to use `this` and also pass in the value as a regular parameter

```
    $('.personName').mouseover(function(event) {
        obj.highlight($(event.target).attr('faceIndex'));
    });
```

ambiguity solved!

Avoid using `this` in JavaScript, if at all possible. It is almost never necessary.

Comment: I thought the argument for an event handler was an `Event`, not a jquery-object containing the node (per your example)?

Comment: excellent point. `el` is passed usually to map and each and filter. I forgot `on` is different. Fixed

Comment: Short-answer is good (minus the typo in `target`), but the long answer here is a lot of _weird_ opinion about `this`, and the last line strikes me as pretty inflammatory.

Comment: @Mathletics I have lots of *weird* opinions, that's true. "Avoid using `this`" is an opinion. What is not an opinion is that in Javascript, `this` is fundamentally a parameter. That is objective as is made clear by the functionality of `.call`. My opinion comes from connecting the dots. If `this` is fundamentally no different from any other parameter, and it is one of the most confusing concepts in javascript, why on earth use it over a regular parameter?

Answer (score 2):

A typical pattern to work around this is to use a local variable to store the first `this`:

```
var obj = {
    foo: function() {
        var _this = this;
        $('.personName').mouseover(function() {
            _this.highlight($(this).attr('faceIndex'));
        });
    }
}
```

Using a language like TypeScript or an ES6 compiler makes it easier to use this pattern without having to write the `_this` by hand each time.

Comment: why? he already has a reference to `obj` right there. Also, if you're going to use that pattern, [please give variables meaningful names](http://togakangaroo.github.io/2013/04/29/stop-that-equals-this-ing).

Comment: but naming things is [one of the hardest problems in computer science](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html).

Comment: @George the most meaningful name would be "this", but unfortunately that's already taken. I'd totally recommend using a better language which allows using "this" inside lambdas (even just a more modern version of JS would be fine), but if you've got to work around it by hand, it seems better to do a mechanical workaround that is the same everywhere, rather than to introduce new variable names each time. Typically I'd expect "obj" inside a function to refer to some other obj, not "this" obj, so re-using that name seems like it could lead to unnecessary confusion.

Comment: Coming back to this (didn't pop up in my inbox) I guess I'll reply with [this blog post I wrote](http://togakangaroo.github.io/2013/04/29/stop-that-equals-this-ing). When you have a choice, you can almost always find a more descriptive name for a variable than `this`.

Comment: I think we're going to have to agree to disagree here, I'm advocating for meaningful names, and you're advocating for descriptive names. Those two strategies are not always going to overlap.

Answer (score 1):

`this` in javascript is a very difficult thing to understand in callbacks because it may refer to virtually any instance. And that is because the callback is called from a different context.

The long story : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

#### As an alternative to previous answers :

One way I prefer dealing with it is by using a `bind`, also known as a `proxy` (in JQuery). jQuery has one implemented here : [jQuery.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/).

It has the benefit of letting you chose who is your `this` in the callback function.

For example:

```
var obj = {
    foo: function() {
        $('.personName').mouseover($.proxy(function(event) {
          // this refers here to obj instance
          console.log(this);
          // event is a jQuery decorated that holds the reference of your element 
          console.log(event);
        }, this));
    }
};
```

And the true benefit of it, is that it lets you construct components that don't have "ugly" nested callback anonymous functions:

```
var obj = {
    foo: function() {
        $('.personName').mouseover($.proxy(this.mouseOverCallback, this));
    },
    mouseOverCallback : function(event) {
       // this refers here to obj instance
       console.log(this);
       // event is a jQuery decorated that holds the reference of your element 
       console.log(event);
    }
};
```

Comment: good point, but I would clarify that `proxy` is jquery-specific terminology. The more general concept is `.bind`. At this point, this function exists by default on any function in any remotely modern browser.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I'll look into it cause I didn't knew, An honest marketing phrase for JQuery would be : "JQuery, shading native JavaScript since 2006."